# How to index a function call for all objects in a vector? - for peformance improving

Tags: matlab, oop, indexing

in a matlab script I have a vector which contains different instances of the same class. Now I would like to call the same function of each instance at the same time.

Is it, with tricky indexing, possible to do this WITHOUT a loop? For Example:

```
runner(1:100) = Human();
runner(:).run('fast');     % causes no error and no function call
```

In my project there is a vector with different neuronal networks (as objects). I tried to propagate all forward with one call.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's one way if you're willing to modify your methods. What happens when you call something like `runner(:).run('fast');`? Rather than pass an instance of `Human()` to the `run` method 100 times it instead passes the entire vector of objects (an [object array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html)) to the method one time. Print out the object input from inside the method and see for yourself. Because nothing happens in your case, your `run` method must be written in such a way to ignore non-scalar objects. What you need to do is vectorize your methods. Depending on the nature of your methods, this may mean using `for` loops in some cases, but it will likely be the faster and more elegant option as it minimize the number of function calls.

Of course another option is to just call the `run` method 100 times using a `for` loop. If you really want "one call" then just hide the loop in a function or if you don't mind things to be a bit slower, use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) which is nothing more than a function that hides a `for` loop:

```
arrayfun(@(obj)run(obj,'fast'),runner(:));
```